# "Network path not found"-error in asp.net (C#) in connectionstring

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, connection-string

I´d like to know if there is anything wrong in this code because it doesn´t connect to the datasource. If i do it with an SQLDataSource in the aspx file there is no error. But why don´t the commands work within my code-behind .cs-file? I hope you understand my problem because i´m just new in .net-coding.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
        //string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDB"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "selectcommand";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source.com;Persist Security Info=True;Password=xxxxxxxxx;User ID=system");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

It says: "Network path not found"

*Row 40:             da.Fill(ds);*

If i add a Provider into the SqlConnection it says: "Keyword not supported: Provider" <-- that´s why i deleted it out of the command.

Comment: Did you specify `http://` or `https://` in front of the adress? Also, you may need to specify a port number.

Comment: No, where do i have to do it? And how do i put in the port number? do you have an example code?

Comment: Internet sources should always be specified with the full protocol:
`http://google.com` is an example. And for the port, just add the `Port=3306` keyword in the connection string.

Comment: Usually it is MySql that listens at port 3306. The OP seems to be using Sql Server.

Comment: yeah.. it just responds "keyword not supported: port" now. but i still don´t know where to specify the http://

Comment: i´m trying it now with an odbc-connection but it seems to be the same mistake (after i deleted `provider` and `Dsn` out of the string `Provider=MSDAORA; Dsn=Oracle32;uid=system;pwd=xxxxx`